# Characterizing convex functions by a Jensen-type inequality

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, convex-analysis, jensen-inequality

Let $\phi:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ be a convex function. Then one can prove by Jensen's inequality that 
$$\tag{$*$} \phi \left(\int_\mathbb{R}xg(x) \, dx \right) \leq \int_\mathbb{R}\phi (x)g(x) \, dx $$ for every $g$ such that $\int_\mathbb{R}g(x) \, dx=1$ and $\int_\mathbb{R}|x|g(x) \, dx < +\infty$.

Now

> suppose that $\phi$ is continuous and $(*)$ holds for every $g$ with the hypotheses above; is it true that $\phi$ is convex?

The intuition coming from other cases already treated before on this site suggests this should be the case, I'm looking for a proof or a reference.

Comment: You also need $g\ge 0$

Answer (score 2):

Take a sequence $g_n$ converging to $\theta \delta_a + (1 - \theta)\delta_b$ in the weak sense of measures. One concludes that $\phi(\theta a + (1 - \theta) b) \le \theta \phi(a) + (1 - \theta)\phi(b)$. As $a$ and $b$ are arbitrary real numbers and $\theta\in [0,1]$, the convexity of $\phi$ follows.

Comment: Thanks for your answer:) How do I prove such a sequence exists? Why does it suffice that it converges a.e. ?

Comment: @zartagtag This is a well known fact, for example if $\psi$ is non negative and has integral 1, then $n \psi(n (x - a))$ converges to $\delta_a$. You can add more constraints such as $\psi$ having a compact support. In our case you can take $\theta n \psi(n(x - a)) + (1 - \theta)n \psi(n(x-b))$

Comment: mhhh I'll look into that. Why is the a.e. convergence sufficient?

Comment: I'm not seeing the convergence.. can you give me a reference for this fact? Thank you for your comments.

Comment: @zartagtag The convergence is simply that for all continuous $f$, one has $\int f g_n d x \longrightarrow \theta f(a) + (1 - \theta) f(b)$. It doesn't have anything to do with a.e. convergence. For a reference see a textbook about integration such as Rudin: real and complex analysis.

Comment: Sorry, I misinterpreted because you said "converge in the weak sense of measures", and I intend that as a.e. convergence. Anyways, how does one show that $\int f g_n d x \longrightarrow \theta f(a) + (1 - \theta) f(b)$ ?